# How to get the position of the checked checkbox in a table

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a table with bunch of checkboxes in each row. How can I find position of the checked box e.g. 1A or 1B when both or one of the checkboxes is checked in first row. The page I am trying to modify, dynamically makes the table based on two factors for the rows and columns. SO I just need to grab the rowname and colname in order to program further. e.g. 10(A) if the name of first row was '10'.

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td align="center"> A </td>
        <td align="center"> B </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <tr> <button id="save">Click</button> </tr>
```

Comment: Why don't you give your checkboxes names?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu like this? `<td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1;1" /></td>`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu though the page I am trying to modify, dynamically makes the table based on two factors for the rows and columns. SO I just need to grab the row# and col# in order to program further.

Comment: Why not `document.getElementById('mytable').children[1].children[1].checked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the column and row of a checked `input`, and it gets the column letter and row number through calls to **[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**, using CSS3 `first-child` and `nth-child` selectors based on the column and row:

```js
document.getElementById('mytable').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    var td= e.target.parentNode,   //the input's td parent
        tr= td.parentNode,         //the td's tr parent
        col= td.cellIndex,         //the input's column
        row= tr.rowIndex,          //the input's row
        header= document.querySelector('#mytable tr:first-child td:nth-child('+(col+1)+')').textContent,
        number= document.querySelector('#mytable tr:nth-child('+(row+1)+') td:first-child').textContent;
    
    document.getElementById('output').textContent= number+header;
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td align="center">A</td>
    <td align="center">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is how I am trying to use it [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaur/8qpsgez0/31/) but it is not working for me.

Comment: That's because you're mixing JavaScript and jQuery.  Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/py3m1v6z/

Answer (score 1):

try this @ plain javascript:

```
var checkboxes = [];
for(var i =0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;i++) { 
 if(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked) {checkboxes.push(i)}
}
```

checkboxes is an array of checked checkboxes - e.g. [0,2] if the first and the 3rd checkboxes are checked

Comment: what if the row name was '10' for row#1 and '2' for row#2, I need to get 10,2 in the checkboxes array.

Answer (score 0):

or like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/zLy90w40/1/

```
 function getCheckBox(){
    var oneA = document.getElementById('1a');
    var oneB = document.getElementById('1b');
    var twoA = document.getElementById('2a');
    var twoB = document.getElementById('2b');
    if (oneA.checked){
        alert("1 A was checked") ;
    }
    if(oneB.checked){
        alert("1 B was checked") ;
    }
    if(twoA.checked){
        alert("2 A was checked") ;
    }
    if(twoB.checked){
        alert("2 B was checked") ;
    }
    }
```